# angular-cli keeps throwing Error: Cannot find module 'source-map'

Tags: npm, angular-cli

So I installed the angular-cli using `npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular` but every time I try and use the `ng` command I get this error: `Error: Cannot find module 'source-map'` 
even trying `ng version` throws the error.  I also trying installing it using `npm install angualt-cli` but that didnt work either.  Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: have you tried, npm install -g @angular/cli ? Say 'y' to everything and then, enter your project and you'll be able to use 'ng'. Tested right now.

Answer (score 3):

I tried a lot of things and ended up just giving up and running npm install source-map which solved it for me.